# Building dynamic SQL query string in python

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am using Python 3.7 and pyodbc.

I have an outer query:

```
for a in allSurveyID:
SurveyId = a[0]

if a == allSurveyID[0]:
    strQueryTemplateOuterUnionQuery = "SELECT UserId, " + str(
        SurveyId) + " as SurveyId Dynamic_Answers FROM [User] as u WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Answer " \
                                                                        "as a WHERE u.UserId = a.UserId AND a.SurveyId = " + str(
        SurveyId) + ")"
    print(strQueryTemplateOuterUnionQuery)

else:
    strQueryTemplateOuterUnionQuery = "UNION " + "SELECT UserId, " + str(
        SurveyId) + " as SurveyId  Dynamic_Answers FROM [User] as u WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Answer " \
                                                                        "as a WHERE u.UserId = a.UserId AND a.SurveyId = " + str(
        SurveyId) + ")"
    print(strQueryTemplateOuterUnionQuery)
```

This returns:

```
SELECT UserId, 1 as SurveyId Dynamic_Answers FROM [User] as u WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM 
Answer as a WHERE u.UserId = a.UserId AND a.SurveyId = 1)
UNION SELECT UserId, 2 as SurveyId  Dynamic_Answers FROM [User] as u WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM Answer as a WHERE u.UserId = a.UserId AND a.SurveyId = 2)
UNION SELECT UserId, 3 as SurveyId  Dynamic_Answers FROM [User] as u WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM Answer as a WHERE u.UserId = a.UserId AND a.SurveyId = 3)
```

In "Dynamic Answers", I am building Answer Columns, which are as follows:

```
currentSurveyIDs = cursor.execute("""

                    SELECT *
               FROM
               (
                  SELECT
                     SurveyId,
                     QuestionId,
                     1 as InSurvey
                  FROM
                     SurveyStructure
                  WHERE
                     SurveyId = ?
                  UNION
                  SELECT 
                     ? as SurveyId,
                     Q.QuestionId,
                     0 as InSurvey
                  FROM
                     Question as Q
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS
                  (
                     SELECT *
                     FROM SurveyStructure as S
                     WHERE S.SurveyId = ? AND S.QuestionId = Q.QuestionId
                  )
               ) as t
               ORDER BY QuestionId
                """, SurveyId, SurveyId, SurveyId).fetchall()

for b in currentSurveyIDs:
    survey = (b[0])
    questions = (b[1])
    InSurvey = (b[2])

    # If the question is in the survey, proceed with the AnswerColumn template query
    questionIds = []
    surveyIds = []
    if InSurvey == 1:
        questionIds.append(questions)
        surveyIds.append(survey)
        AnswerCol = list(zip(surveyIds, questionIds))

        for c in AnswerCol:
            strQueryTemplateForAnswerColumn = ",COALESCE ((SELECT a.Answer_Value FROM dbo.Answer a WHERE " \
                                              "a.UserId = u.UserId AND a.SurveyId = " + str(surveyIds[0]) + " AND " \
                                                                                                            "a.QuestionId = " + str(
                questionIds[0]) + "),-1) AS ANS_Q" + str(questionIds[0])
            print(strQueryTemplateForAnswerColumn)

    elif InSurvey == 0:
        Nulls = []
        Nulls.append(questions)
        strQueryTemplateForNullColumnn = ",NULL AS ANS_Q" + str(Nulls[0])
        print(strQueryTemplateForNullColumnn)
```

This returns:

```
,COALESCE ((SELECT a.Answer_Value FROM dbo.Answer a WHERE a.UserId = u.UserId AND 
a.SurveyId = 1 AND a.QuestionId = 1),-1) AS ANS_Q1
,COALESCE ((SELECT a.Answer_Value FROM dbo.Answer a WHERE a.UserId = u.UserId AND 
a.SurveyId = 1 AND a.QuestionId = 2),-1) AS ANS_Q2
,NULL AS ANS_Q3
,NULL AS ANS_Q4
,NULL AS ANS_Q1
,COALESCE ((SELECT a.Answer_Value FROM dbo.Answer a WHERE a.UserId = u.UserId AND 
a.SurveyId = 2 AND a.QuestionId = 2),-1) AS ANS_Q2
,COALESCE ((SELECT a.Answer_Value FROM dbo.Answer a WHERE a.UserId = u.UserId AND 
a.SurveyId = 2 AND a.QuestionId = 3),-1) AS ANS_Q3
,NULL AS ANS_Q4
,COALESCE ((SELECT a.Answer_Value FROM dbo.Answer a WHERE a.UserId = u.UserId AND 
a.SurveyId = 3 AND a.QuestionId = 1),-1) AS ANS_Q1
,COALESCE ((SELECT a.Answer_Value FROM dbo.Answer a WHERE a.UserId = u.UserId AND 
a.SurveyId = 3 AND a.QuestionId = 2),-1) AS ANS_Q2
,NULL AS ANS_Q3
,NULL AS ANS_Q4
```

I have all the strings I need in these two sections. What I am stuck on is how to put them together where I get all the questions per survey such as

```
SELECT
                UserId
                , 1 as SurveyId
                ,COALESCE ((SELECT a.Answer_Value FROM dbo.Answer a WHERE a.UserId = u.UserId AND a.SurveyId = 1 AND a.QuestionId = 1),-1) AS ANS_Q1
                ,COALESCE ((SELECT a.Answer_Value FROM dbo.Answer a WHERE a.UserId = u.UserId AND a.SurveyId = 1 AND a.QuestionId = 2),-1) AS ANS_Q2
                ,NULL AS ANS_Q3
                ,NULL AS ANS_Q4

        FROM
            dbo.[User] as u
        WHERE EXISTS
        (
                SELECT *
                FROM Answer as a
                WHERE u.UserId = a.UserId
                AND a.SurveyId = 1
        )
UNION
```

And so on with Survey 2 and 3.
Thank you for any input.

Comment: your first qiery seems to be a subset of the latter expanded to all 3, so wy tpo you wnt to combine them you wouldn't get more infomation by joining them

Comment: I need the final query resulting in the pivoted data in order to update a view dynamically.

Comment: it is impossible to sorry, you should break akk down to smaller functions that return the parts that are equal or differ only by a number.